# Match any characters more than once, but stop at a given character

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regex that will be used for recognizing commands in a string. I have three possible words the commands could start with and they always end with a semi-colon.

I believe the regex pattern should look something like this:

```
(command1|command2|command3).+;
```

The problem, I have found, is that since `.` matches any character and `+` tells it to match one or more, it skips right over the first instance of a semi-colon and continues going.

Is there a way to get it to stop at the first instance of a semi-colon it comes across? Is there something other than `.` that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are facing with this:  `(command1|command2|command3).+;` is that the `+` is greedy, meaning that it will match everything till the last value.

To fix this, you will need to make it non-greedy, and to do that you need to add the `?` operator, like so: `(command1|command2|command3).+?;`

Just as an FYI, the same applies for the `*` operator. Adding a `?` will make it non greedy.

Answer (score 3):

Tell it to find only non-semicolons.

```
[^;]+
```

Comment: +1. Why do most folks insist on _always_ (unnecessarily) using the dot when a more precise tool (like this one) does a better job? (I guess when the only tool you have is a hammer...)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a **non-greedy** match.

```
.+?
```

The `"?"` after your greedy `+` quantifier will make it match **as less as possible**, instead of as much as possible, which it does by default.

Your regex would be

```
'(command1|command2|command3).+?;'
```

See **[Python RE documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)**

Comment: The quantifier was `+` not `*`